# Meaning of "sup my homeslice? harvard jv field hockey is da bomb..."

Tags: meaning, slang

I completely don't understand what this star's line means, even though the words are simple.

> sup my homeslice? harvard jv field hockey is da bomb...

What's *homeslice*?
What does *da* mean?

Comment: Do things not seem a bit incongruous about this sentence to anyone else? Ivy prep school sports meets SoCal slacker slang...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. **Sup**: Actually `'sup?` abbreviation of "What is up?"; "What is happening?"
2. **homeslice**: friend; variant of "homes", "homey", "homebrother", originally implying someone from your neighborhood "home", but now simply slang for "buddy."
3. **da bomb**: 'da' = 'the' so 'the bomb'; something really good.
4. **jv**: Junior Varsity, the team below Varsity, usually composed of anyone who wants to play rather than players selected by the coach for performance.

So my translation would be:

> What is happening, friend? Harvard Junior Varsity field hockey is really good.

Comment: I think you've nailed the _original_ meaning of **homeslice**, but it might be worth noting to the OP that it probably hasn't been used in that context in quite some time. Now it seems it's just a silly term thrown about among friends.

Comment: Sure thing, homes.

Comment: Note that you'll occasionally see "Holmes" as a stand-in for "homes." I agree that "homeslice" is losing currency.

Answer (score 4):

- *sup* is an interjection that is quicker to write but basically means the same as what's up (last three letters).
- *da* is a colloquial phonetic spelling of "the".
- *homslice* is a slang for "buddy", "pal", "mate".
- *Harvard jv* stands for [Harvard Junior Varsity](http://www.gocrimson.com/information/junior_varsity/index).
- *field hockey* is the [sport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_hockey).

So stitching up all this translates as:

> What's up mate ? The Harvard Junior
>   Varsity Field Hockey team is the bomb!

Comment: Good call on the JV.

Comment: I might translate this as, "Greetings and salutations my esteemed colleague. Harvard's Junior Varsity field hockey program is most excellent."